# On the Frobenius group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, arithmetic, group-presentation, frobenius-groups

I am studying some properties of Frobenius group  $G$ of order $20$, which mean that a presentation of the group  $G$ is

$$G = \langle c, f \mid  c^5 = f^4 = 1, \,cf = fc^2\rangle.$$

My question is that true $f^2c = cf^2$? I use the following simple proof:

$$\begin{align}
cf = fc^2 &\Rightarrow fc = c^2f\\
&\Rightarrow  ffc = fc^2f\\
& \Rightarrow f^2c = cff\\
& \Rightarrow f^2c = cf^2.
 \end{align}$$

I think Its seems trivial but I need confirmation because the given reasoning help to get more relations betwen $c$ and $f$.

Answer (score 2):

$cf=fc^2⇒fc=c^2f$. This step is false. You can take inverses of the first words to get $f^{-1}c^{-1}=c^{-2}f^{-1}$, but you cannot just reverse words. In fact, no (non-trivial) power of $c$ commutes with any (non-trivial) power of $f$.

Comment: So is that true: $f^{-1}c^{-1} = c^{-2}f^{-1} \Rightarrow  f^{3}c^{4} = c^{3}f^{3} $ ? because we have $c^5 = f^4 = 1$. And I need to know why you say " In fact, no (non-trivial) power of c commutes with any (non-trivial) power of $f$"

Comment: The equation $cf=fc^2$ tells you how to change every string of letters involving $c$ and $f$ into a word of the form $f^ic^j$. So $c^2f=c(cf)=c(fc^2)=(cf)c^2=(fc^2)c^2=fc^4$. Thus $f$ and $c^2$ don't commute, and neither do $f$ and $c^4$. You can repeat this exercise to check any pair.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your interest,, you are helping me

Answer (score 1):

The relation $f^2 c = c f^2$ would imply that
$$f^{-2} c f^2 = f^{-1} (f^{-1} c f) f = f^{-1} c^2 f = (f^{-1} c f)^2 = c^4$$
is equal to $c$. But $c^3 = 1$ and $c^5 = 1$ force $c = 1$, which is not the case in $G$. (This is immediate if you know that your group has order $20$, since the condition $c = 1$ would then force $G = \langle{f:\, f^5 = 1\rangle} = \mathbb{Z}_5$. Without that, we could use the presentation of $G$ to define a suitable homomorphism onto some group of order larger than $5$.)

The problem in your proof is that $xy = zw$ does not imply $yx = wz$; in fact, $xy = w$ does not imply $yx = w$.  The group $G$ is not abelian, and in particular is not just $\mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: you are absolutly right, thanks for your proof and ideas.